# core data in tabviewcontroller

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, tabbar

I have a core data application which shows data in table view. it works well with following code:

```
 self.mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
 self.mainViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

 self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

however, when i try to implement the code to embed in tabbar application, it does show the tabbar but without core data. core data is being saved but they are not displayed in tableview. below is the code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

NSArray *arrController = [tabBarController viewControllers];
UINavigationController *navController = [arrController objectAtIndex:0];
MainViewController *controller = [navController. viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should reference your tabBarController and use it's context. The issue I'm sure you are having is the managedObjectContext is not properly passing to your views. Pass your context to the tabBarController and then access that context from your views of your tabBarController. Similar to below.

```
YourTabBarController *tabBar = (YourTabBarController *)self.tabBarController;
self.managedObjectContext = tabBar.managedObjectContext;
```